# ubuntu 14.04 mysql has too many procceses

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, wordpress

I Have UBUNTU 14.04 server and i have installed Openlitespeed - MySQL - WordPress .

My Server Has 4G RAM .

Sometimes my website got hanged and i have to reboot server to fix problem .

I search and some website write about bug in MySQL .

Is it possible my server Got bugged ?

Here is my Htop :

http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00828/plwl6osnrp7c.png

Here is My my.cnf :

```
    [client]
    port        = 3306
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    [mysqld_safe]
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    nice        = 0
    [mysqld]
    user        = mysql
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port        = 3306
    basedir     = /usr
    datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir      = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
    skip-external-locking
    bind-address        = *.*.*.*  (( MY SERVER IP For Remote Uses))
    key_buffer      = 16M
    max_allowed_packet  = 16M
    thread_stack        = 192K
    thread_cache_size       = 8
    myisam-recover         = BACKUP
    query_cache_limit   = 1M
    query_cache_size        = 16M
    log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    expire_logs_days    = 10
    max_binlog_size         = 100M
    [mysqldump]
    quick
    quote-names
    max_allowed_packet  = 16M
    [mysql]
    [isamchk]
    key_buffer      = 16M
    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

i don't change any setting in my.cnf !

please someone help me .

Comment: What exactly do you are using in the `bind_address` setting? A specific IP address that is accessible from the Internet? If that is the case, that is a very bad thing, since you expose your MySQL to remote attacks.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen : i connect to MySQL server remotely from another server ! is there any way to do that securely ?

Comment: Use a VPN for that.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen : i change bind address to local and no change of htop ! i dont think error is about bind address . because i only access to database from my second server ip !

Comment: This was just an observation on your configuration, not a possible reason for the slowness. However, your server is more vulnerable to compromise when you let anyone in the Internet connect to your MySQL port. Does MySQL server log have any information?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen no my error.log is empty ! i wonder why i should have that much MySQL process ! is it normal ?

Comment: Have you checked also `daemon.log`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i don't have any file named daemon.log ! where is location  ?

Comment: `/var/log` is the location for all system logs. If there is no such log, look at the other logs for MySQL related messages.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen not found ! in var/log/mysql folder i have just error.log and empty !

Comment: Did you check the log files inside `/var/log`? It has all the system logs.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i check with **find / -name daemon.log** and didnot find any file . yes there is not such as file daemon.log

Comment: And the other log files in `/var/log`, anything in those?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i have some log files as : mysql.log ( empty ) - yum.log - boot - auth ... !